# Is a subrepresentation just a subspace, or a representation itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, definition

A representation of a group $G$ is a pair $(\rho, V)$, where $V$ is a vector space, and $\rho$ is a homomorphism $\rho : G \rightarrow Aut(V)$.

The definition I've been given for a subrepresentation is: a subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $\rho (g)(W) \subset W, \forall g \in G$.

Is the subrepresentation just the subspace $W$, or is it the representation $(\left. \rho \right|_W , W)$?

Comment: Are you asking if $\rho|_W$ is representation or are you asking about what term subrepresentation refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subrepresentation is the representation $(\left. \rho \right|_W , W)$.  However, it's very common to just refer to this representation as "$W$", much as it is common to refer to a group by its underlying set and not explicitly mention the group operation.